# how to stop my timer after click Finalizar and the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this timer for counting the time and everything is working except when I refresh the page and press "Finalizar" the buttons changed as desired but the timer clock is starting again.

JS how can I fix my javascript code to make it work properly?

```
    visor = document.getElementById("reloj"); //get clock at screen location
//associate button's events: on click, the button activate a function.
    document.cron.boton1.onclick = activo;
    document.cron.boton2.onclick = pausa;
    document.cron.boton1.disabled = false;
    document.cron.boton2.disabled = false;
//intial vars:
    var marcha = 0; //chrono's control
    var cro = 0; //chrono initial status.
    if(localStorage.getItem("visor")!=null)
        {
            // If the browser starts and the initial var is stored
            // into the browser's database of the browser and has a value, we get that value
            // and start the process.
            ini=localStorage.getItem("visor");
            document.getElementById("boton_1").value="Finalizar";
            funcionando();
        }
}
var ini = 0;
var timeout = 0;
//Start / Restart button
function activo() {
    if (document.cron.boton1.value === "Iniciar" && timeout===0) { //"Iniciar" button
        iniciar() //go to start function
        // Obtenemos el valor actual
        ini=new Date().getTime();

        // Guardamos el valor inicial en la base de datos del navegador
        localStorage.setItem("visor",ini);

        // iniciamos el proceso
        funcionando();
    } else {  //"Finalizar" button
        finalizar()  //go to restart function
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        // Eliminamos el valor inicial guardado
        localStorage.removeItem("visor");
        timeout=0;
    }
}

//Pause / Continue button
function pausa() {
    if (marcha === 0) { //with "Continuar" button!
        continuar() //go to continue button
    } else {  //with "Pausar" button
        pausar() //go to pause button
    }
}

//Button 1: Start status: Trigger the chrono
function iniciar() {
    emp = new Date() //initial date (at the moment the button is clicked)
    elcrono = setInterval(tiempo, 10); //timer function.
    marcha = 1 //indicating the chrono is running.
    timeout = 1
    document.cron.boton1.value = "Finalizar"; //Change button status
    document.cron.boton2.disabled = false; //activate "Pausa" button
}

//timer function
function tiempo() {
    actual = new Date(); //instant date
    //chrono's time  (cro) = instant date (actual) - initial date (emp)
    cro = actual - emp; //elapsed milliseconds.
    cr = new Date(); //number converted to milliseconds to date object.
    cr.setTime(cro);
    //get each date format:
    sg = cr.getSeconds(); //seconds
    mn = cr.getMinutes(); //minutes
    ho = cr.getHours() - 1; //hours
    //put 2 number figures
    if (sg < 10) {
        sg = "0" + sg;
    }
    if (mn < 10) {
        mn = "0" + mn;
    }
    if (ho < 10) {
        ho = "0" + ho;
    }
    //show result into the html.
    visor.innerHTML = ho + ":" + mn + ":" + sg;
}

//stop the chrono
function pausar() {
    clearInterval(elcrono); //stop the chrono
    marcha = 0; //indicate the chrono is stopped.
    timeout = 1;
    document.cron.boton2.value = "Continuar"; //change button status
    document.cron.boton2.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
    document.cron.boton2.setAttribute("data-target", "#staticBackdrop");
}

//Continuing a chrono started and stopped.
function continuar() {
    emp2 = new Date(); //actual date
    emp2 = emp2.getTime(); //change time to Unix
    emp3 = emp2 - cro; //substract previous time
    emp = new Date(); //new initial date to pass into the timer
    emp.setTime(emp3); //data for initial date.
    elcrono = setInterval(tiempo, 10); //timer triggered
    marcha = 1; //indicating the timer is started
    timeout = 1;
    document.cron.boton2.value = "Pausar"; //Changing button status
    document.cron.boton1.disabled = false; //activate button 1 if were deactivated
    document.cron.boton2.setAttribute("data-toggle", ""); //add attribute to button 2 for showing the modal
    document.cron.boton2.setAttribute("data-target", ""); //add attribute to button 2 for showing the modal
}

//Come back to initial status
function finalizar() {
    if (marcha === 1 && timeout === 1) {  //if chrono is running:
        clearInterval(elcrono); //stopping the chrono
        marcha = 0; //indicate is stopped
    }
    //in any case we put the chrono on initial status
    timeout = 0;
    cro = 0; //time rune to zero
    visor.innerHTML = "00:00:00"; //visor a cero
    document.cron.boton1.value = "Iniciar"; //first button's initial status
    document.cron.boton2.value = "Pausar"; //second button's initial status
    document.cron.boton2.disabled = true;  //second button deactivated
}

//Getting data whe chrono is stopped
function getFinalData() {
    var final_data = $('#breakOptions').val()
    console.log(final_data)
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

//Selecting an option into the modal when pause the chrono
$('#contador-reason').on("submit",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Checking if form is valid
     if(!$('#contador-reason').valid()){

         alert("Validation failed");
                return false;
            }else {
                 let contador_time = $("#reloj").text()
                 let contador_reason = $("#myOptions option:selected").val()
                 function GetDate() {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    today = yyyy  + '-' + mm + '-' + dd ;
                    return today;
                }
                // Coding
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'view_contador_pause',
                     headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')},
                     method: 'POST',
                     contentType: 'application/json',
                     data: JSON.stringify({
                         'contador_time': contador_time,
                         'option_selected': contador_reason,
                         'contador_date': GetDate()
                     }),
                     dataType: "json",
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (response) {

                         $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');
                         console.log(response)
                     },
                     error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                         console.log("error")
                         console.log(xhr);
                     },
                 });
            }

    return false;
});


$("#button_1").on("click", function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    let contador_time_end = $("#reloj").text()
    function WithoutTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        today = yyyy  + '-' + mm + '-' + dd ;
        return today;
    }
    if($(this).val() === 'Iniciar') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'view_contador_start',
            headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')},
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'contador_time_start': '00:00:00',
                'chrono_date': WithoutTime()
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    }
    if($(this).val() === 'Finalizar') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'view_contador_end',
            headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')},
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'contador_time_end': contador_time_end,
                'chrono_date': WithoutTime()
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    }
});

$("#button_2").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contador',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'option_selected': $("#reloj").text()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
        }
    });
});


function funcionando()
    {
        // Obtain actual date
        var actual = new Date().getTime();

        // Obtain the difference between actual date and initial date 
        var diff=new Date(actual-ini);

        // Showing difference between actual date and initial date
        var result=LeadingZero(diff.getUTCHours())+":"+LeadingZero(diff.getUTCMinutes())+":"+LeadingZero(diff.getUTCSeconds());
        document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML = result;

        // Indicating to restart the function after 1 sec
        timeout = setTimeout("funcionando()",1000);
    }

    /* Function puts a zero before the number if necessary */
    function LeadingZero(Time)
    {
        return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;
    }
```

HTML

This is the HTMl of the timer with the buttons

```
            <div id="reloj">
              00:00:00
            </div>
            <form name="cron" action="#">
                <input class="btn btn-cron" type="button" value="Iniciar" id="button_1" name="boton1" />
                <input class="btn btn-cron" type="button" value="Pausar" id="button_2" name="boton2"  /><br/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?